# Online resources for learning/practicing bridge

Tags: bridge, online

Are there any good online resources to learn the game. By learn, I mean learn attain the knowledge that one would by buying/reading a good book.

For example, are there any "puzzles" that are well explained that either explain different bidding systems or strategies for playing with the dummy etc.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some:

- Richard Pavlicek's [site](http://www.rpbridge.net/) on bridge which has puzzles, articles explaining concepts, bidding systems, calculators etc. A very good free resource.
- The now discontinued [deal of the week](http://bbi.bridgebase.com/dotw/) by Fred Gitelman which is an over the shoulder type of software. Free.
- Bridge Master and software by other world class players: http://bbi.bridgebase.com/cgi-bin/store/commerce.cgi (not free, but highly recommended).

Answer (score 2):

Many newspapers have Bridge Columns and these are often archived online, e.g.

- [Zia Mahmood (The Guardian)](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/series/bridge-with-zia-mahmood?INTCMP=SRCH)
- [Phillip Alder(New York Times)](http://www.phillipalderbridge.com/columns.html)

You can find others by [searching for "bridge column"](http://www.google.com?q=%22bridge%20column%22).

Answer (score -2):

I am developing a site to practice card play for bridge: 
[akqbridge.](http://akqbridge.com/) There is no bidding - you play set contracts.  One key aim is to lower the entry barrier for new players.

Comment: It seems that your only reason for posting is to proselytize.

Comment: Bridge has a problem.  It is a dying game. We need to come up with ways to lower the entry barrier if we want a resurgence in our game. 
Of course, I am trying to promote the game.  I think all bridge players should.  We can't just watch the decreasing numbers at our brigde clubs and do nothing.

As an adjunct to my website, I wonder whether it might be possible to interest young programmers by having an AI competition. Without the need to program the bidding, it should be a simpler problem.  Are you interested in helping me organize it?